# Is it worth it to "test" Lambda functions w/ Lambda Proxy Integration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

If one uses  ["Lambda Proxy Integration"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56188864/aws-lambda-clarification-on-retrieving-data-from-event-object/56191784#56191784) ([here too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52240132/3191929) & [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html)) in API Gateway, there are two important changes that occur:

1) data is mapped to `event.body` (rather than directly on the `event` object requiring mapping templates)

2) `event.body` is stringified and needs to be JSON.parse'd

Here's an example of a simple Lambda function that expects input to conform to Lambda Proxy Integration from API Gateway (node10x)--

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

    if (event && event.body) {
    try {
        event.body = JSON.parse(event.body);
    } catch(e) {
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify({message: 'Hit error in try/catch'})
        }
    }
}
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({message: event})
    }

}
```

**Q:** How (or should) one use Lambda's "built-in" test input feature for a Lambda script that's expecting data in the manner from Lambda Proxy Integration?

The test inputs come directly on the `event` object (not `event.body`) and the data isn't stringified from the test payload

[image]

We can solve #1 if the function is expecting `event.body` we can pass that in for a test but then the event.body is expected to be stringified. We can silently skip the try/catch but that seems a bit clunky

Is there a better technique to send "test" input data to a Lambda function?
Unless I have overlooked something, it seems like you either need to get a better solution or hand-craft the test inputs to "match" the expected payload from an API Gateway invocation w/ Lambda Proxy Integration

Comment: Why don't you put stringified JSON object to "body" key as value in your test event?

Comment: That crossed my mind as well-- I think the bottom line for now is not to rely too much on "testing" Lambdas that way with Proxy Integration and run locally w/ SAM or other tooling ex: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model?source=post_page

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying with default event configuration suggested, have you tried selecting pre-defined test event templates when you try to test your Lambda functions?

You can try Event Template --> API Gateway AWS Proxy.